# Protecting routes in React Native not rendering on first load

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm new to react native , I have several screens that are protected according to the condition if the user is logged in or logged out, the way I'm doing this is that I have created 2 stacks one called `AppStack` which is when the user is logged in and the other is the `AuthStack` which is when the user is logged out, the checking is being made in a NavStack and according to the condition the Stack is being rendered, the problem I'm facing is that when the app first opens or I reload the app the screens are not being rendered even though the console.log in the screen is working and is consoling to the terminal but the component is not being rendered, it renders only when I manually change the state of the loggedIn user then only the screens are being rendered, I'm not getting any error messages so I'm not able to figure where the problem is or how to fix it,

App.tsx :

```
import './src/localization/i18n';
import useAuthStore from './src/store/auth-store';
import NavStack from './src/routes/NavStack';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavStack/>
  );
};

export default App;
```

NavStack.tsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import AppStack from './AppStack';
import AuthStack from './AuthStack';
import useAuthStore from '../store/auth-store';

const NavStack = () => {
  const {isLoggedIn} = useAuthStore();
  console.log(isLoggedIn)
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      {isLoggedIn ? <AppStack /> : <AuthStack />}
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default NavStack;
```

AppStack.tsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import HomeScreen from '../screens/HomeScreen';
import QrCodeScreen from '../screens/QrCodeScreen';
import VerifiedScreen from '../screens/scanned-qr/VerifiedScreen';
import UnVerifiedScreen from '../screens/scanned-qr/UnVerifiedScreen';
import UsedCardScreen from '../screens/scanned-qr/UsedCardScreen';
import Privacy from '../screens/terms-privacy/Privacy';
import Terms from '../screens/terms-privacy/Terms';
import ContactUs from '../screens/ContactUs';
import ChangePassword from '../screens/auth/ChangePassword';
import SplashScreen from '../screens/SplashScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AppStack = () => {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
    //   initialRouteName="Home"
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      {/* <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} /> */}
      <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="QrCode" component={QrCodeScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Verified" component={VerifiedScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="UnVerified" component={UnVerifiedScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="UsedCardScreen" component={UsedCardScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Privacy" component={Privacy} />
      <Stack.Screen name="Terms" component={Terms} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ChangePassword" component={ChangePassword} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ContactUs" component={ContactUs} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AppStack
```

AuthStack.tsx :

```
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import LoginScreen from '../screens/auth/LoginScreen';
import ForgotPassword from '../screens/auth/ForgotPassword';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AuthStack = () => {
    console.log("Logged out")
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}
    //   initialRouteName="Login"
      >
      {/* <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen} /> */}
      <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name="ForgotPassword" component={ForgotPassword} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};

export default AuthStack
```

and this is the store , I'm using zustand :

auth-store.tsx :

```
import {create} from 'zustand';

interface AuthState {
  isLoggedIn: boolean;
  setIsLoggedIn: (newValue: boolean) => void;
}

const useAuthStore = create<AuthState>(set => ({
  isLoggedIn: false,
  setIsLoggedIn: newValue => set({isLoggedIn: newValue}),
}));

export default useAuthStore;
```

Answer (score -1):

Ok so I have found the answer , I basically need to add a loader and wait for the data is ready for renedering, if the loading state is true i render a loading component , if false then the navigator will navigate according to whether the user is signed in or not

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).